# Why does mergesort have at most 6 n log n array accesses?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, mergesort, array-algorithms

I'm watching the Coursera Princeton algorithms lecture on merge sort and I understand all of the analysis except for a merge being at most 6 n log n array accesses.

Why 6?

Comment: 6 is very implementation dependent, I would say.

Answer (score 2):

To get 6 array accesses, a somewhat inefficient merge process:

```
read  - read an element from even run for compare
read  - read an element from odd  run for compare
      - compare
read  - read the lower element again for copy
write - write the lower element to the output array for copy
...   - after merge copy back
read  - read element from output array to copy back
write - write element back to original array to copy back
```

The normal case is one read and one write for every element moved, but consider the case where elements are too large to fit in a variable, like a string, so after a compare, the string to be moved has to be read again.

Usually the copy back operation can be avoided, depending on how the merge sort is coded.

Comment: @njzk2 - the most common case is if the element is too large to fit in a register (like a string). I updated my answer to mention this.

Answer (score 0):

I also wondered about the 6. I watched Tim Roughgarden's analysis (video '1 - 7 - Merge Sort- Analysis (9 min).mp4') and he says six as well. Each explanation feels like hand waving, but maybe because it's so simple they didn't realize it needed explanation:

You access an array twice for each n (or k) when you copy to the auxiliary array 
`aux[k] = a[k];`
Then, in the worst case you never exhaust a sub-array (where you're only comparing constants) such that you have four more array accesses
`else if (less(aux[j], aux[i])) a[k] = aux[j++];` (e.g., if the input is in reverse order) or each compare fails and the else kicks in after the compare (correct order), or some combination of the two. That doesn't matter, just that by definition of the worst case you can't escape array accesses via constants (with the `if (i > mid)` or `else (j > hi)`) so you've got four more here for each k. Total is 6.

(Each line of code is Sedgewick's - page p271 of his text.)